# Want to add script tag combination to html head using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a ad tag like below which I dynamically want to add to head using javascript.

```html
<script language="JavaScript"> var zflag_nid="2710"; var zflag_cid="1914"; var zflag_sid="144"; var zflag_width="300"; var zflag_height="250"; var zflag_sz="9"; </script> <script language="JavaScript" src="http://xp2.zedo.com/jsc/xp2/fo.js"></script>
```

1. I tried putting it by using methods over internet but it is getting added as string.
2. If the below tag is put in head of any html page I can see ad but I want to add it using javascript. (no jquery plz)
3. I have many tags like this so whenever a tag like this comes to me. I will need to add it to head using javascript. So it is basically taking input as above and putting it in head for such script combination.

Comment: How do you mean "dynamically"? How are you getting the data?

Comment: @Dan White:- I mean i have this script tag above and want to add it using javascript to head. maybe I should just remove that word dynamically.

Comment: @wostex has your answer...

Comment: @Dan White:- I have many tags like this so whenever a tag like this comes to me. I will need to add it to head using javascript. So it is basically taking input as above and putting it in head.

Comment: So slap it in a function and reuse the function in a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty straightforward:

```js
const h = document.head;

const s1 = document.createElement('script');
s1.innerHTML = `var zflag_nid="2710"; var zflag_cid="1914"; var zflag_sid="144"; var zflag_width="300"; var zflag_height="250"; var zflag_sz="9";`;

const s2 = document.createElement('script');
s2.src = 'http://xp2.zedo.com/jsc/xp2/fo.js';

h.appendChild(s1);
h.appendChild(s2);
```

Inspect iframe DOM after running this script - your tags are inside `head` section of html.

Swap `const` to `var` if needed for browser compatibility.